# How to write integration test cases using spock framework

Tags: grails, spock

I am using Grails-2.4.4.I need simple steps to write integration test cases using spock in grails.

I created a sample application in that i am just persisting a record in database.I want to write integration test cases for that.

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Please, write here your Class code to create a custom test for you

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @quindimildev that it will be easier to provide helpful information once an example Domain class is given - especially if there are specific things to test. Until then, I know it can be helpful even just to see the start of a test, so here is one such example:

Let's say there is an `Author` domain class

```
class Author {
    Integer id
    String screenName

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache usage: 'read-only' // No writes to the database
        table 'exp_members'
        id column: 'member_id'
        screenName column: 'screen_name'
        version false // Prevent a version column from being added to the database table
    }
}
```

You could then have an integration test that looks like this:

```
@TestFor(Author)
@Mock([Author])
class AuthorSpec extends Specification {

    void "test"() {
        when:
        Author author = new Author(
                screenName: "Jon Doe",
                id: 1
        ).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        then:
        Author.count() == 1
    }
}
```

Here are some helpful notes about this test:

`@TestFor(Author)` is used to specify which object will be mocked, in this case it is the `Author` domain class, but it can also be a controller for controller integration tests.

`@Mock(Author)` Indicates which domain class should be mocked, and which domain class can have Gorm methods applied to it. This can also be an array, if you have multiple domain objects to mock for this test. For example: `@Mock([Author, Book])`

`.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` is good to use for fake persisted entries. `flush: true` will make sure entries are immediately saved and available for your test. `failOnError: true` will fail the test if the save did not work properly. This is very helpful in case you missed a constraint, and without this it will fail later, with a more cryptic message.

`Author.count() == 1` you can see that after the save you can immediately query for it with the Gorm `count()`.

NOTE: The `IntegrationSpec` class is no longer available in Grails 3. Instead, the class should extend `Specification` (just like a unit test), and include the `@Integration` annotation.

Comment: He uses Grails 2.4, so his integration test does have to extend IntegrationSpec

Comment: @loteq I added the comment in case anyone came along later and was looking at this question, because it might not be apparent to some that the switch from Grails 2 to Grails 3 was a major overhaul.